azure batch update only one property of a job
I have some python code to create a job, and add some tasks. I want the job to OnAllTasksComplete.terminate_job, but I can't set this during job creation since then it will complete immediately before I have a chance to add tasks. So I do it after.
Here my python code to update a job:
job = batch_service_client.job.update(job_id=job_id,job_update_parameter=batchmodels.JobUpdateParameter(on_all_tasks_complete=batchmodels.OnAllTasksComplete.terminate_job))

However, according to the documentation, the above snippet of code will not update only this property, but reset all other properties (constraints, etc.). Is there an elegant way to do this?

Updated answer
I agree with you, When I update Job property rest all properties are reset.
Additionally, According to this job_update_parameter official MS Document.

If the current value is terminatejob, this is an error because a Job's completion behavior may not be changed from terminatejob to noaction. You may not change the value from terminatejob to noaction - that is, once you have engaged automatic Job termination, you cannot turn it off again. If you try to do this, the request fails and Batch returns status code 400 (Bad Request) and an 'invalid property value' error response.

Once you set the OnAllTasksComplete  to terminate_job You cannot change it back.
And job_update_parameter only supports below parameters -
(*, pool_info, priority: int = None, max_parallel_tasks: int = -1, allow_task_preemption: bool = None, constraints=None, metadata=None, on_all_tasks_complete=None, **kwargs)

When I tried updating priority with job_update_parameter  even that failed:-
job_update_parameter = batchmodels.JobUpdateParameter(
    pool_info=pool_info,
    on_all_tasks_complete=batchmodels.OnAllTasksComplete.terminate_job,
    priority=100,
)

Output:-
Error:-
aise models.BatchErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.batch.models._models_py3.BatchErrorException: Request encountered an exception.
Code: JobCompleted

But when I create a batch job from scratch with the desired properties using job_add_parameter ,
The properties are added successfully:-
from azure.batch import BatchServiceClient
from azure.batch.batch_auth import SharedKeyCredentials
from azure.batch import models as batchmodels

# Initialize Batch client
credentials = SharedKeyCredentials('siliconbach90', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX==')
batch_service_client = BatchServiceClient(credentials=credentials, batch_url='https://siliconbach90.australiaeast.batch.azure.com')

# Define job ID and pool ID
job_id = 'new_job_id'
pool_id = 'pool2'

# Create pool info
pool_info = batchmodels.PoolInformation(pool_id=pool_id)

# Define job parameters
job_add_parameter = batchmodels.JobAddParameter(
    id=job_id,
    pool_info=pool_info,
    on_all_tasks_complete=batchmodels.OnAllTasksComplete.terminate_job,
    on_task_failure=batchmodels.OnTaskFailure.perform_exit_options_job_action
)

# Create the job
batch_service_client.job.add(job_add_parameter)
print(f"Job '{job_id}' created successfully in pool '{pool_id}' with specified properties.")

Output:-


Old Answer:-
You can retrieve the existing job properties and then modify the job with desired properties, Refer the code below:-
from azure.batch import BatchServiceClient
from azure.batch.batch_auth import SharedKeyCredentials
from azure.batch import models as batchmodels

# Initialize Batch client
credentials = SharedKeyCredentials('siliconbatch67', '0xxxxxxxxxxxxABayxF3UQ==')
batch_service_client = BatchServiceClient(credentials=credentials, batch_url='https://siliconbatch67.australiaeast.batch.azure.com')

# Retrieve current job properties
job = batch_service_client.job.get(job_id='B2py', job_get_options=batchmodels.JobGetOptions(select='id'))

# Create pool info
pool_info = batchmodels.PoolInformation(pool_id='B2py')

# Modify the properties you need to change
job_update_parameter = batchmodels.JobUpdateParameter(
    pool_info=pool_info,
    on_all_tasks_complete=batchmodels.OnAllTasksComplete.terminate_job
)

# Update the job with the modified properties
batch_service_client.job.update(job_id='B2py', job_update_parameter=job_update_parameter)

Output:-


You do not use the existing job properties anywhere. They will be reset to default like this.

@ZironCode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-batch/azure.batch.models.jobaddparameter?view=azure-python Did you try this method to update the properties, Ideally its not possible but you cn add the new parameters using this dependency!

@ZironCode Check my Updated answer, I agree with you, When I update Job property rest all properties are reset.
Additionally, According to this job_update_parameter official MS Document.

If the current value is terminatejob, this is an error because a Job's completion behavior may not be changed from terminatejob to noaction.


the problem is, as posed in the question, that if I create a job under these terms, it completes immediately since I cannot add tasks to it.p.s. I edited out your private key from the solution

my current solution is to have an azure function run on a timer, and terminate jobs manually if all tasks are completed. this does not feel elegant.

Ideally it should complete all tasks and then terminate the job, Is this not happening?
